# Mandrill send API will queue email occasionally

Tags: api, mandrill

My email will occasionally get queued instead of sending download link **immediately** using  a paid Mandrill account- other times it will send quickly. I would like it to be send at time of calling the API. The are no errors in the Mandrill API control panel.

This code works great most of the time via a node server on Heroku...I am using 'send_at' parameter w current Date using the javascript Date() method. How can I send an email consistently - sometimes queues can be 1 hour 30 min long.

```
// Text version of message
me_data.text += message;

// Html for message
me_data.html = results['html'];

// current Date for sending
var sendDate = new Date();

mandrill_client.messages.send(
    {"message": me_data, "async": async, "ip_pool": ip_pool, "send_at": sendDate}, 
    function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        //success 
    }, 
    function (e) {
        //_____________________________Error
        console.log('A mandrill error occurred: ' + e.name + ' - ' + e.message);
    }
);
```

Comment: How are you measuring the 1h 30m delay? Is mandrill reporting that in the dashboard?

Comment: I am using Heroku, Node Mandrill API to send() email and I have the time stamp, status "sent", and "_id" of the transaction. Additionally I didn't see outgoing in the control panel in Mandrill until later after email was sent. Finally I can see the delay using gmail header analytic tool by pasting in the original email. Do you have any advise about how to go about making sure it's sent when I call- or a least a short time later? Thanks for any help anyone may have! Appreciated

Comment: If anyone is finding same can you pls post here, or if you have a solution! Thanks

Comment: `send_at` is an optional parameter. If you want to send mail immediately is shouldn't be passed. You might also want to pass `async` as true to get the messages delivery status (it's not clear from your example if you're doing this already).

Answer (score 1):

This issue is no longer a problem. Please ignore the above posts about the time parameter as I am using this variable (clearly `"send_at"` from API doc) and Mandrill is sending.

This must have been a fluke of timing as I had paid a short time before launching production app. You have to pay (set credits) in Mandrill to use the `send_at` parameter - in other words upgrade from the free version. It may take some time to come into effect.

Mandrill has been working flawlessly since this issue like quick as lighting. So this is not an issue any longer for my stuff.